# Beanstalk: eb deploy erroring out with Invalid length for parameter EnvironmentName, value: 25, valid range: 4-23

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-linux

I have a Beanstalk environment which has been running since more than a year now. It's running *Python 3.6 running on 64bit Amazon Linux*, which is now deprecated and I need to migrate to Amazon Linux 2 separately.

Out of nowhere, I am not able to do eb deploy to my environment anymore. It throws an error saying

```
ERROR: Parameter validation failed: 
Invalid length for parameter EnvironmentName, value: 25, valid range: 4-23
```

The environment name has never changed after it was created. Why is this error all of a sudden?

My awsebcli version is 30.20.2

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my awsebcli version was not correctly setup in the virtual env, even though pip upgrade etc was not able to catch it. Resolved by setting the virtual env again.